# Rotation and circular motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Can we consider rotation of an object about an axis as an extremely complicated form of circular translation as radius becomes very small. If not, what is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot.

Translation in Euclidean space, any dimensional Euclidean space, is abelian (order doesn't matter) while rotation in Euclidean space, at least beyond two dimensional Euclidean space, is non-abelian (order **does** matter).

Comment: But this isn't true for infinitely small angular rotations, they will commute